# ¿Cómo comprobar dos fechas TimeStamp en Java Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando crear un validador de fechas en Java, la actual con una obtenida de un json y que está en formato TimeStamp `2016-01-18 18:12:56`

Para obtener los milisegundos de la fecha actual utilizo lo siguiente

```
public static long GetCurrentTimeStamp() {
    Date date= new Date();
    return date.getTime();
}

public static long ConvertTimeStampToDecimal(String fecha) {
    //Me falta convertir TimeStamp a Milisegundos 
}

long DateNowDecimal = GetCurrentTimeStamp();
String TimeStampDB = "2016-01-18 18:12:56";
```

me falta como convertir el contenido de `TimeStampDB` a milisegundos para luego comprobar si es inferior o superior a la de actual, para determinar si actualizar datos o no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solucionado!**
Con la respuesta de [@Jose Antonio Dura Olmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2853/c%C3%B3mo-comprobar-dos-fechas-timestamp-en-java-android#2855) añado el siguiente código para la solución.
El final no uso lo de obtener los milisegundos de la fecha actual ya que siempre se estaría actualizando.

**Función GetTimeStamp()**

```
public static long GetTimeStamp(String TimeStampDB) {
    Date fechaConvertida = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        fechaConvertida = dateFormat.parse(TimeStampDB);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred"+ e.getMessage());
    }
    return fechaConvertida.getTime();
}
```

**Dependencias**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
```

**Código de testeo:**

```
long localJsonDate = GetTimeStamp("2016-01-10 23:00:12");
long remoteJsondate = GetTimeStamp("2016-01-18 18:12:56");

System.out.println("now Date: " + String.valueOf(localJsonDate)); 
System.out.println("JSON Date: " + String.valueOf(remoteJsondate));  

if (remoteJsondate > localJsonDate)  {
    //Se debe actualizar datos
    System.out.println("Necesita actualizar datos...");
} else {
    System.out.println("Datos actualizados!");
}
```

**Resultado:**
Se debe actualizar datos ya que la fecha del JSON remoto es superior a la última del JSON local

Answer (score 2):

Convierte la cadena de caracteres a un `Date`

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date fechaConvertida = dateFormat.parse(TimeStampDB);
```

Y convertir de `Date` a milisegundos ya sabes hacerlo tu mismo.

Comment: Grácias, más o menos ya tengo la solucíón